# NavigationBar Layout has an exception when user has in call status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

After I toggle in-call status bar, the navigation bar drops. And the content behind falls a height of 20 .

I can not figure out why.

The picture shows the scene.

[image: 1]

Looks like the navigation bar drops. And the blue bar falls.

Seen from the view hierarchy debugger, I do not know why the blue bar has a distance from the navigation bar.

[image: 2]

Here is the relevant code.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
      self.blueBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
      [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
      [self.blueBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
      [self.blueBar.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
      [self.blueBar.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
      [self.blueBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: 75].active = YES;
      ......
}


-(UIView *)blueBar{
    if(!_blueBar){
        _blueBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
        _blueBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return _blueBar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar height change from 20 to 40 when in-call.And I found you use tableView,so try this:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} else {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

What's more,why not use mainstream framework`Masonry`?

Comment: Apple's layout constraint ( the second version ) is very easy to use. In Swift.